# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, livereload

Hi I've assigned a existing running project after the previous developer left the company.I just cloned the project from github and did bundle. On running the project I get the following error on browser console.

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

It is my first day in office and it is ruining me.

Here is my gem file content

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
  gem 'rack-livereload'
  gem 'rb-fsevent',       require: false
  gem 'guard-rspec',      require: false
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'zeus', '0.15.1'
  gem 'i18n-tasks', '~> 0.6.2'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

and In development.rb I've also this line

```
  # Automatically inject JavaScript needed for LiveReload
  config.middleware.insert_after(ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::LiveReload)
```

I don't know what is the problem. Did I need to run separate server for LiveReload? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to run `bundle exec guard` in order to run the make livereload monitor.

Comment: Where do I run this command? Which folder? I get the error - `bundle: command not found`. But when I run `npm bundle --version` i get 
`3.10.3`.

Comment: Please, tell how and where to run this command. Thank-You

Answer (score 0):

You could find the process listening at the port and kill to restart.

Command to find the processes related to the port

```
lsof -i :35729
```

Command to kill the process.

```
kill -i pid
```